# Test case/plan for error message scenarios

Tags: testcase, test-planning

I am working on a project that has an application that has several different specific error messages that are raised during certain scenarios with specific data.  I have been tasked to come up with a Test Case/Plan which can be given to testers to test this.

e.g. user loses internet connection and error code x is displayed
     user account is locked and error code y is displayed

Can anyone recommend a template that can be used to do this?  I have very little QA experience.

Comment: I think you need to provide some more specifics for folks to help you.  With your example you may actually be on the right track.  Your test cases should be and action and the expected result.  If you think of things from that stand point it may help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's really no different than any other test case.

Set up conditions:

Check actual result against the expected result

So you'll need a list of all the error messages in the system and the conditions that make these errors appear

If you want to really test them out then use the FAILURE mnemonic as detailed [here](http://www.questioningsoftware.com/2007/08/failure-usability.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can write the test cases for the above scenario as normal test cases. Just make sure that you cover the complete error codes in your test cases so that all can be covered and tested thoroughly.

Specific error messages along with each error code will be of great help for testers as well as developers in finding out the bug and fixing them.