# How to find the specific error on a web page from a generic message page?

Tags: manual-testing, web-application, firebug

While testing Web pages, Sometimes the page would be Redirect to **RUNTIME** error **Compilation** error.

I could not fine what is the exact reason for the errors.
As a QA is want to know what was the exact error. while reporting the Bug to developer

I have tried Firebug, it results the redirect page alone.

Is there any other tool or plugin to find the reason for the Redirecting occurs?

Comment: See also http://sqa.stackexchange.com/q/6102/8992

Comment: Error cannot be of both runtime and compilation type. And at server runtime you rather have seen runtime error unless your server compiles something at runtime ;)

Comment: @dzieciou A lot of web technologies compile on first use. Like the unfortunate souls who have to use JSPs.

Comment: @corsiKa Woa! I didn't know. And didn't know someone still uses JSP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now you need to report that you got the Runtime Compilation error page.  That is what was generated by the web server for you and is all you can tell from outside the system, if just using the web to test.  Make sure however that you details the environment tested in (os, browser, version, etc) and the steps to reproduce (URL for host and any parameters) and make sure they still reproduce the error (unless it is intermittent, reason unknown).

Separately you should also seek to improve the situation:

The approach to test will also depend on where you are testing.

When testing locally, i.e. running the server locally and using a browser then you can look at the code, the application log that is being generated and its errors and messages.

When testing on staging, work with the developer to add additional information to that error page so that you have more information to report in the case of error. This will benefit local testing also.

If you are testing production, you should find a way for this information to be placed in logs you can access or sent via an email that you can read or a web report you can access.  The existing message about runtime compilation is already both too technical and too informative.  bots might love it!  I would recommend seeking a more generic apology message in the production environment but with details still captured via log and/or email.

Answer (score 2):

The server may log more detailed information. I would ask the developer where to look.

Comment: i will also do the same, But here, Developers advising to report the Exact error... so i am searching for the tool or plugin to find the exact error...

Comment: The exact error may not be exposed to the client at all, but should be logged server side.

Answer (score 1):

**Things which you can try:**

1. Try generating multiple scenarios and make sure if it's reproducible after few steps.
2. Check if it occurs by clicking on particular element on webpage, if yes then inspect the element and find out the root cause.
3. Try debugging, adding breakpoints for js if any.
4. Try access the server logs and investigate the error.
5. Try looking it if user is redirected to error page after specific time.

If nothing works, you can report the bug to developer and get exactly what was cause of issue, so you can reproduce and retest it in future.